# How to change directory before executing HG commands from firefox extension?

Tags: mercurial, firefox-addon

I am trying to execute hgtk log command for a particular file. But you cannot do it until you are in the repository directory.

something like this...

```
process.initwithpath("cmd.exe"); 
args = ["CD","c:\\MY_REPO"];
process.run(true,args,args.length);
process.initwithpath("hg.exe"); 
args= ["hgtk","my_file.txt"]; 
process.run(true,args,args.length);
```

But the problem is second process will not keep track of first one....

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `--repository` command line option (short from is `-R`). It will change the current working directory of `hgtk` before executing log, annotate, etc. If you provide a filename on the command line, then you should beware that they are understood relative to the argument of `-R`. So this works:

```
hgtk -R ~/src/mercurial log README
```

because the `README` file is found relative to `~/src/mercurial`. This also works

```
hgtk -R ~/src/mercurial log ~/src/mercurial/README
```

since we give the full path to the `README` file. In this sense it works like Mercurial's `--cwd` option. Mercurial also has a `-R` option, but this does not change the current working directory.

Comment: that works...that was really helpful and give a good insight for how to use hgtk command with different options...

Thanks a zillion !!!